# Can't delete empty elements from objects inside an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with this structure:

```
{"fecha":"24-07-2019",
  "local_id":"5",
  "local_nombre":"AHUMADA",
  "comuna_nombre":"LA CALERA",
  "fk_localidad":"12",
  "localidad_nombre":"LA CALERA",
  "local_direccion":"J J PEREZ 199",
  "funcionamiento_hora_apertura":"09:00 hrs.",
  "funcionamiento_hora_cierre":"08:59 hrs.",
  "local_telefono":"+563326316573",
  "local_lat":"-32.7882065329844",
  "local_lng":"-71.189446195146",
  "funcionamiento_dia":"Miercoles",
  "fk_region":"6"
}
```

Sometimes 1 or 2 elementos of this objects are empty `""` and **i need to delete them**.

The problem is that I've tried many things to delete them but I always get an array of `null` objects.

**What I've tried**

```
  const deleteEmpty = obj => {
    for (let prop in obj) {
      if (obj[prop] === null || obj[prop] === undefined) {
        console.log(obj[prop])
        delete obj[prop]
      }
    }
  }

// Supose my array of objects is in a const named 'objArr'
   const newObjArr = objArr.map(obj => {
     deleteEmpty(obj)
   })
```

**Also tried with**

```
   const newArr = objArr.map(obj => {
     Object.keys(obj).forEach(
       key => obj[key] === null && delete obj[key]
     )
   }
```

As I said, I get an array of `nulls` same length as the first array I put through the delete process. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Regards.

Comment: Try to check null as well as undefined for each object value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

deleteEmpty does not returns the obj back

```
const deleteEmpty = obj => {
  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (obj[prop] === null || obj[prop] === undefined) {
      console.log(obj[prop])
      delete obj[prop]
    }
  }

  return obj
}
```

Comment: :facepalm: .. thank you sir.

Answer (score 6):

You have to return the object at the end of the function

```
  const deleteEmpty = obj => {
    for (let prop in obj) {
      if (obj[prop] === null || obj[prop] === undefined) {
        console.log(obj[prop])
        delete obj[prop]
      }
    }
    return obj
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if by empty you mean empty strings "", then you should include that in your check, empty strings are not equal null or undefined

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce` to make copies of the elements, simply ignoring any blank values:

```js
const elements = [{
  "fecha": "24-07-2019",
  "local_id": "5",
  "local_nombre": "AHUMADA",
  "comuna_nombre": "LA CALERA",
  "fk_localidad": "12",
  "localidad_nombre": "LA CALERA",
  "local_direccion": "J J PEREZ 199",
  "funcionamiento_hora_apertura": "09:00 hrs.",
  "funcionamiento_hora_cierre": "08:59 hrs.",
  "local_telefono": "",
  "local_lat": "",     //Blank
  "local_lng": "",     //Blank
  "funcionamiento_dia": "Miercoles",
  "fk_region": "6"
}, {
  "fecha": "24-07-2019",
  "local_id": "5",
  "local_nombre": "",   //Blank
  "comuna_nombre": "LA CALERA",
  "fk_localidad": "12",
  "localidad_nombre": "LA CALERA",
  "local_direccion": "J J PEREZ 199",
  "funcionamiento_hora_apertura": "09:00 hrs.",
  "funcionamiento_hora_cierre": "08:59 hrs.",
  "local_telefono": "", //Blank
  "local_lat": "-37.6",
  "local_lng": "24.5",
  "funcionamiento_dia": "Miercoles",
  "fk_region": "6"
}];

const copyWithoutBlanks = el => {
  return Object.entries(el).reduce((accum, entry) => {
    const [key, val] = entry;
    if (val.trim().length) {
      accum[key] = val;
    }
    return accum;
  }, {});
};

const noBlanks = arr => arr.map(copyWithoutBlanks);

console.log(noBlanks(elements))
```

Comment: This helped me understand that the function I pass to `.map` doesn't need to be like `.map(obj => deleteObj(obj))`. That returned null again. I just passed `.map(deleteObj)` and voilá. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, exactly - it can simply be a reference to the function (just be sure your parameters match). Glad it helps!